# react useFormHook default values not working with react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-hook-form

I am having issue in setting default value of radio button using react-hook-form library the text input is working fine but i cant figure outa way to set the radio button value. Below is the attached code sandbox of the said issues  [enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-react-bootstrap-forked-qgo5oy?file=/src/App.js)